# How to make sum query with type casting and calculation in django views?

Tags: django, django-views, django-signals

I'm calculating the sold items cost in django views and in django signals, and I want to calculate sold items cost on the fly. Price and quantity fields are integers. How can I convert one of them to the float and make sum query with some calculations like these sql queries below?

```
SELECT sum((t.price::FLOAT * t.quantity) / 1000) as cost FROM public."sold" t;

SELECT
t.id, t.price, t.quantity, sum((price::FLOAT * quantity) / 1000) as cost
FROM public."sold" t
GROUP BY t.id;
```

**EDIT:** Of course expected results are querysets of django

I expected the output of first query

```
             cost
-----------------
5732594.000000002
```

and I expected the output of second query

```
 id    price  quantity    cost
------------------------------
846     1100      5000    5500
790     1500      1000    1500
828     2600      1000    2600
938     1000      5000    5000
753     1500      2000    3000
652     5000      1520    7600
```

**EDIT 2:** I solved this issue via `raw()` method like

```
MyModel.objects.raw(
    'SELECT sum((t.price::FLOAT * t.quantity) / 1000) as cost '
    'FROM public."sold" t'
)
```

instead of pythonic way

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have a look into a couple of things to do that. The first one will be aggregation and annotation. Also, you'll need to look into Cast and F functions. Please have a look at the links below:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#cast

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/

***DISCLAIMER:*** This is an example and might not work

Your queryset will look something like this:

```py
from django.db.models import FloatField, Sum
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

qs = MyModel.objects.annotate(cost=Sum(F(Cast('price', FloatField())) * F('quantity') / 1000))
```

Comment: Yes this example is not worked. The error is 'Cast' object has no attribute 'split'.
I solved this issue via raw() method like `MyModel.objects.raw('SELECT sum((t.price::FLOAT * t.quantity) / 1000) as cost FROM public."sold" t;')` instead of pythonic way

Comment: It’s hard to say why because you didn’t share you code so it might anything. But in fact you’re not using Django DB functions properly because you still have you raw query. As I said, I believe that could be solved without any raw sql query.

Comment: I think so. I will share my code, just not today. I think it need to be simplified