# Adding an annotation to django queryset to be used by django_tables2

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-tables2

I have a model that has (among other fields) one value for the current price of an item and one value for the usual price of an item. I'd like to include a field for the percentage saving. I've done this using the @property:

```
@property
def percSaving(self):
    aval = self.stickerprice
    bval = self.currentprice
    if self.stickerprice > 0:
        return  "%0.2f" % ((aval-bval)/aval*100) + "%"
    elif self.currentprice == 0:
        return "Always Free"
    else:
        return "100% OFF"
```

This works, I can add this column to my django_table2 table with:

```
percSaving = tables.Column(verbose_name='% Saving')
```

Super easy and all good. However, I am unable to sort by this column. This is because it's not one of the columns of data from the query set. So I've been trying to annotate the query set to allow for this ordering I've based by annotation attempt on this [queryset api reference page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/) and have produced this:

```
annoed = products.objects.annotate(percSaving=((stickerprice)-(currentprice))/(stickerprice))
```

However this gives me an error of "*name 'stickerprice' is not defined*" which I thought might be because of not using inverted commas around the field names, but I tried that and got an error saying "*unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'*" - basically using the inverted commas forces it to view the field names as strings.

What am I doing wrong? How can I annotate a query set to allow for ordering by a column I have defined as above!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. With providing some more code like Model etc. I can only make some general advise.
You should use F function to calculate in the query like:

```
    annoed = products.objects.annotate(
        percSaving=((F("stickerprice") - F("currentprice")) / F("stickerprice"))
    )
```

Check also [How to make sum query with type casting and calculation in django views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56196815/how-to-make-sum-query-with-type-casting-and-calculation-in-django-views) which provides also some type casting hints.