# Casting inside a django query

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a model with two properties

```
class Player(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    score = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I want the score to remain a CharField but now I want to average the scores of all players through a simple query like this

```
Player.objects.aggregate(Avg('score'))
```

This will not work because "score" is a CharField and needs to be cast to a float first. How do I go about typecasting it on the fly? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why is `score` a `CharField`, and not an `IntegerField`/`FloatField`? Converting this to numbers will be quite expensive for the database since parsing a `string` to an `int` is not that fast.

Comment: I came to the project late in the game, I don't know for sure but I think it had something to do with pymongo not liking those types. For now, I need to implement a simple feature and later I will fix that issue when I get a grasp of what that change entails. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "Cast" like this :

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
Player.objects.annotate(score_as_float=Cast('score', 
output_field=FloatField()).aggregate(Avg('score_as_float'))
```

Source : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#cast

[How to make sum query with type casting and calculation in django views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56196815/how-to-make-sum-query-with-type-casting-and-calculation-in-django-views)